# How to say "mix of two language" in a bad meaning

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there is a invective for "mix of two language".

But the word slipped my mind.

Can you tell me how to say it?
I'm not intend to use it, I only want to remember the word.

Comment: Creole does not have the negative connotation you are looking for and are usually used to refer to mixtures of European languages.  "Spanglish" is sometimes used in a slightly disparaging context.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: Found the expression "macaronic language" at Wikipedia, that might fit in some cases. One may also try adding some adjectives to imply an awkward mix, such as, "mongrel, jumbled, pastiche" + language etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two categories are [*creoles*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_language) and [*pidgins*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin). They're both "mixed heritage" languages, but only *creoles* have native speakers (so only they can really be said to have functional grammar).

Arguably therefore, ***pidgin*** is more derogatory, since it usually applies to less-developed languages. On the other hand, you might think ["parvenu"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parvenu) ***creole*** children would be looked down on by native speakers of the contributory languages (as lacking any clear linguistic/cultural heritage).

There's also [***barbarous*** language](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22barbarous%20language%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [*barbaric language*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22barbarous%20language%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22barbaric%20language%22&tbm=bks), and [*barbarisms*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22barbarous%20language%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22barbarisms%22&tbm=bks) (which are often linguistic). And for those who don't know the etymology of [*barbarian*](http://www.altalang.com/beyond-words/2008/10/08/etymology-of-barbarian/)...

> To the Greek ear, someone who did not speak the Greek language babbled, producing the onomatopoeic sound *“bar bar bar”* which became *bárbaros*, and later *barbaria* in Latin.

Answer (score 1):

How about "pidgin"?

From wiki: "Fundamentally, a pidgin is a simplified means of linguistic communication,.. Pidgins usually have low prestige with respect to other languages."